# Format AM/PM DateTime to 24 hour time

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, time

I have a data 
`9/14/2019 4:37:57 PM`

I want to format this to: 20190914T**16**3757

How do I format it so that if it includesPM to 24hour using ampscript?

Comment: Is the data a text / aka string or is it inside a dataextension and the type date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get exactly your desired output using the following:

```
%%[
SET @time = "9/14/2019 4:37:57 PM"
SET @formatted = Replace(FormatDate(@time, "YYYYMMDDT","HHMMSS"),' ','')
]%%
%%=v(@formatted)=%%
```

> Output: 20190914T163757

Answer (score 6):

The closest you can get to this is by using the [FormatDate](https://ampscript.guide/formatdate/) AMPscript function with ISO pattern:

```
set @dateString = "9/14/2019 4:37:57 PM"
set @dateISO  = FormatDate(@dateString,"iso")
```

`%%=v(@dateISO)=%%` outputs: 2019-09-14T16:37:57.0000000

You can then format this further using [Replace](https://ampscript.guide/replace/) and [Substring](https://ampscript.guide/substring/) functions:

```
set @dateString = "9/14/2019 4:37:57 PM"
set @dateISO  = FormatDate(@dateString,"iso")
set @dateReplace = Replace(Replace(@dateISO, "-", ""), ":", "")
set @dateSubstring = Substring(@dateReplace,1, Subtract(IndexOf(@dateReplace,"."),1))
```

`%%=v(@dateSubstring)=%%` outputs: 20190914T163757